# httpclient PostAsJsonAsync errors after (n) messages (port exhaustion?)

Tags: c#, azure, runtime-error, httpclient, azure-webjobs

I have a Console App(webjob) running in Azure that calls an API also running in azure. The Console App posts messages from a csv file.
When I run the Console App from my local (windows 10) machine (with the api running in azure) it works as expected (no errors).
When I run the Console App in Azure (with the api running in azure) it processes approx 980 messages and then starts reporting errors

Errors:

- "An error occurred while sending the request"
- "Unable to connect to the remote server"

I believe that for some reason when the Console App is running in Azure it is exhausting the ports but I do not know how to resolve this.
My file has 50,000 rows but as stated only ever reaches approx 980 before issue arrises.
At the other end the api is posting the received messages to a sql database and to an azure event hub.
How can I force the application to release the port once the PostAsJsonAsync has completed?
How can I check to see that the port has been release or how can I check that a port is available?
If you are aware of any other reasons that i may be getting these errors please help.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<string> PostMessageToAPI(string aMsg)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string strResponse = "";    
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.SetBearerToken("access token here");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyBaseUrl.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            using (response =  await client.PostAsJsonAsync("my/url/goes/here", anEvent.ToLower()))
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {       
        //  exception message states: "An error occurred while sending the request"
    }   
    return strResponse;           
}
```

- Visual Studio 2015 update 3
- .net 4.5.1
- Azure Console App Plan : Basic 1 small
- Azure API App Plan : Basic 1 small

Comment: Is `PostMessageToAPI` called from a multi-threading environment?

Comment: It is called from an Azure WebJob and so multiple instances can be called but this is managed by Azure. i am however testing just a single instance.

Comment: Who/what is at the remote server? Is it possible that the connections at that end are not disconnected properly?

Comment: What kind of a trigger is used in your web job? - time/queue/blob? reason being if queue you have the flexibility of setting up the number of messages you can/need to process and also the ability to lease and relase locks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please do not use `HttpClient` wrapped in `using`. Use a static instance and share it.

```
public class MyClass()
{
private HttpClient client = null;
public MyClass(){
    client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken("access token here");
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyBaseUrl.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

}
public async Task<string> PostMessageToAPI(string aMsg)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    string strResponse = "";    
    try
    {
        using (var response =  await client.PostAsync("my/url/goes/here", new StringContent(aMsg, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")))
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                else
                {
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {       
        //  exception message states: "An error occurred while sending the request"
    }   
    return strResponse;           
}
}
```

You could even share the same instance of the Class, the point is, it is not optimal to recreate and reopen the socket everytime, it will eventually lead to Socket Exhaustion depending on your call throughput.

[Source](http://www.westerndevs.com/Deployment/httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Note: there are only 9 methods [that are actually thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) `CancelPendingRequests`, `DeleteAsync`, `GetAsync`, `GetByteArrayAsync`, `GetStreamAsync`, `GetStringAsync`, `PostAsync`, `PutAsync`, and `SendAsync`. None of the properties are guaranteed to be thread safe. Make sure your  `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method does not use any methods not in that list and does not use any of the properites.

Comment: Good catch! I just ported the code for static usage, that's the reason behind the Port Exhaustion.

Comment: Hi Matias, the problem was that I was creating the httpclient anew for every call. I now reuse the same httpclient  for all the calls and the issue is resolved. This is essentially what you have described in your code so thanks. I have marked your answer as the solution.